# High throughput in-memory database for temporary storage of images

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, in-memory-database

I'm looking for a high throughput in-memory database for storing binary chunks of sizes between 1.5MB to 3MB (images).

The use case is live video stream computer vision inference pipeline, where we have multiple deep models doing inference on 720p video at 25FPS in real-time. Our current solution is Amazon FSX with Lustre, which can handle the task (average throughput is 180MB/s). The models are in their own K8s pods and read the decoded video frames from the FSX. The problem is that it takes a long time to setup for each run and it's not optimal, since in order to increase the throughput you also need to pay for extra space, which we don't really need, since the storage is temporary and most of the time less than a 1000 frames are stored at once. Ideally, we would have an in-memory database on an instance, which can be lifted up fast and is can have a very high throughput (up to 500MB/s).

I've tested Redis and Memcached as an alternative, but both fail to achieve similar performance, which I assume is due to large chunk sizes (as far as I know both are meant for many smaller sized chunks and not for larger ones).

Any suggestions on what else to test or in what direction to look would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this [Cockroach Labs – Community Forum –"In-Memory" CockroachDB?](https://forum.cockroachlabs.com/t/in-memory-cockroachdb/2936/2) useful? (Also, following this, deeply curious about the responses you get.)

Comment: High throughput of what? Provide your read and write access patterns

Comment: Binary chunks of size ~3MB (images), where we need a throughput of at least 200MB/s.

Comment: I wouldn't call 200MB/s high throughput... Would an optimized postgres db work for you? Or you can use one of the fancier tooks others are describing here.

Comment: Alternatively, you can store your images in blob storage (AWS S3 or eq) and store the urls in your cache / memory db.

Comment: The latency of AWS S3 is way too large for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at eXtremeDB. I work for the vendor (McObject), so hopefully this won't get flagged as 'commercial' since you asked for ideas. eXtremeDB has been used for facial and fingerprint recognition in access control systems. Not exactly the same use case, but perhaps similar enough to warrant a look.